# JSON Decode via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, decode

I have a JSON file, but I can't decode it like any other JSON file.
Where am I making a mistake?

```
$jsonData = '[[[],[{"file_id":"2_U_3","sub_file_id":"2_U_3_1","option_file":[0,3.44827586207],"file_votes":1}],[],[],[],[]],{}]';

$jsonDec = json_decode($jsonData, TRUE);

echo $jsonDec["file_id"] . " = " . $jsonDec["option_file"][2];
```

> Result: empty screen

Comment: You have a syntax error on the `$jsonData` assignment line, because you're using double quotes as the string delimiter and also inside the string.

Comment: Use single quotes around the string: `$jsonData = '[[[],[{"file_id":"1_697","sub_file_id":"2_48281",option_file":[0,0,57,28,14,0]}]';`

Comment: I made a nail error when editing the JSON file for the question. The original file does not have a nail error. I realized there was a missing part in JSON and I made the editing. I also looked at your profile. You're like PHP & JS professor. :) @Barmar

Comment: `option_file` only has 2 elements, so the indexes are `0` and `1`. What are you expecting to print with `[2]`?

Comment: `echo $jsonDec[0][1][0]['file_id'] . " = " . $jsonDec[0][1][0]["option_file"][1];` prints `2_U_3 = 3.44827586207`

Comment: Yes! I told you. You're a professor! I'm waiting for your post to accept dear professor @Barmar

Comment: I'm not posting an answer, I already closed the question as a duplicate of a general question that shows how to solve this in general.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your time! @Barmar